# Possibility of stale data in cache-aside pattern

Tags: caching, design-patterns, memcached

Just to re-cape cache-aside pattern it defines following steps when fetching and updating data.

**Fetching Item**

1. Return the item from cache if found in it.
2. If not found in cache, read from data store.
3. Put the read item in cache and return it.

**Updating Item**

1. Write the item in data store.
2. Remove the corresponding entry from cache.

This works perfectly in almost all cases, but it seems to fail in one theoretical scenario.

What if step 1 & 2 of *updating item*, happen between step 2 & 3 of *fetching item*. In other words, consider that initially data store had the value 'A' and it was not in cache. So when fetching item, we read 'A' from data store but before we put into the cache, the item was updated to 'B' in another thread (So 'B' was written in data store and tried to remove the entry from cache, which was not there at that time). Now when the fetching thread puts the item it read (i.e. 'A') in cache. So now 'A' will stay cached, and further fetches will return stale data, until item expires or updated again.

So am I missing something here, is my understanding of pattern is wrong. Or that the scenario is just practically impossible, and there is no need to worry about it.

Also I would like to know if some changes can be made in the pattern to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the pattern appears perfectly correct, according to the [MSDN definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx). In fact, it mentions the same failure scenario that you describe.

> The order of the steps in this sequence is important. If the item is removed before the cache is updated, there is a small window of opportunity for a client application to fetch the data (because it is not found in the cache) before the item in the data store has been changed, resulting in the cache containing stale data.

The MSDN article does note that, "*it is usually impractical to expect that cached data will always be completely consistent with the data in the data store.*" Expiration and eviction are two strategies mentioned for dealing with this problem.

An old computer science [joke](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) goes like this.

> There are only two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

You've stumbled upon the first of these problems.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the same MSDN artical, but my understanding of quoted note was that it's talking about steps of updating item (problem with removing from cache before updating store). Anyway setting shorter expiration seems to be only remedy, but it's a constant overhead to avoid a theoretical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I would like to know if some changes can be made in the pattern
>   to avoid this problem.

There is no way to avoid this situation in general. Memcached protocol introduces a special command:

```
"cas" is a check and set operation which means "store this data but
  only if no one else has updated since I last fetched it."
```

Scenario should be modified:

**Fetching Item**

1. Return the item from cache if found in it.
2. If not found in cache, read from data store.
3. Check and swap the corresponding entry in cache and return it.

**Updating Item**

1. Check and swap the corresponding entry in cache.
2. Write the item in data store.

This scenario also does not guarantee full consistency.

Imagine the following situation:
Writing item in data store fails, while updating item in cache succeed. The latest item value will be kept in cache only.